# How to convert int to char in java? Why it works? How to prevent information lost?

Tags: java

I read couple posts about converting int to char. But none of them address my question in detail. Like I want to convert 5 to '5'. It's narrowing conversion since int has 4 byte while char only  has 2 bytes. I got two question here:
1. why (char)(a + '0') can convert a to char successfully while (char)a fails?
2. How to make sure no information get lost in this conversion?

Comment: You need to understand Unicode values.

Comment: You are aware that an `int` contains values up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2^31 - 1) whilst a `char` only contains one "integer" digit? So, a loss is inevitable for int > 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why (char)(a + '0') can convert a to char successfully while (char)a fails?

This is because `a + '0'` is equivalent to `a + 48`, which is `53`. This corresponds to the character `'5'`.
Just converting the `int` value `5` to a `char` creates a non-printable `char`, which is what you interpret as not working.

> 2. How to make sure no information get lost in this conversion?

You can check if the value in `a` is small enough to fit in a `char` using [`Character.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE).

Answer (score 0):

The char type can only represent a single character, so you can only convert numbers from 0 to 9. If you want larger numbers as text then use a String, e.g.

```
String str = a + "";
```